# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment Variables in Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

Recently I have been trying to deploy a django webapp to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and everything has been going fine. However part of my app uses that Twitter API so I need to import my API keys. My understanding is that I should use Configuration > Software Configurations > Environment Properties. I set this up inputting my keys but when I checked the site it still failed.

I have been using this to try and import the variables is that correct?

```
import os

os.enviorn.get('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
```

I checked to see if the variables were making it to the server and when I ran `eb printenv` I was shown this:

```
 Environment Variables:
     TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = XXXXX
     TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET = XXXX
     TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = XXXX
     TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = XXXXX
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key you are trying to get doesn't exist among your environment variables. Changing the code to -
`os.environ.get('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')` or any other key among your env vars should do the trick.

Comment: I was using the correct variable names. I changed it in the question to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Have you tried sshing into the server and checking if the env var contains the desired value? by using `echo $TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN`, for instance?

Comment: from `eb ssh MY_ENVIRONMENT` I ran printenv and couldn't see the Twitter API keys and `echo $TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN` did not work. Is there a specific place in the EC2 where I should be checking?

Comment: However if I run `. /opt/python/current/env` then I can access them. So they are making it to the server.

Comment: OK, that is pretty strange. What happens if you print out the results of your `os.environ.get` command? Does it return none? Maybe there are some caveats into working with env vars and beanstalk.

Comment: Speaking from my experience - in my company we keep these kind of secrets in an s3 bucket and download into the app as a part of the beanstalk deploy process.

Comment: How would you go about doing that. The reason I was doing it this way is I usually use a config.py file, but since I'm setting up automated deployment I wanted to have it less manual.

Comment: Thanks a lot I think its actually something else within my Twitter API setup. Sorry to swallow up your time.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for accepting my answer. About the config file - the eb instances are assigned an IAM role, if you allow that role access to your bucket you can use the awscli to get objects from the bucket containing the config files, you can download it as part of the build process (usually by using the .ebextension folder)

Answer (score 8):

In order to get system environment from AWS Elastic Beanstalk Properties (which is not OS environment variables) you need to "source" it to your environment. In case of Python, EB Properties are stored at /opt/python/current/env file. So simply run this command:

```
source /opt/python/current/env
```

Now you got your env variables updated.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I just ran a test with a very simple Django website, adding an endpoint to dump out the entire environment. All of the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` variables in my `.ebextensions/foo.config` are in the environment of the WSGI process (as well as the `container_commands` processes, which is indirectly how I ended up at this question).